# File not found on Docker run inside Makefile

Tags: docker, makefile

I am trying to do a `docker run` inside a Makefile and it fails with a `File not found error` but the same command works fine on my terminal.

Here is the command that I am running from my terminal which works fine.
`docker run -it image_name command_name scripts/`

My Makefile looks like this

```
run-commands:
    docker run -it image_name command_name scripts/
```

I get `ERROR: file not found: scripts/` error while running `make run-commands`. Giving the absolute path does not work as well.

Any ideas why I am seeing this error?

Comment: Presumably because the directory `./scripts` isn't in your container, but there's some missing details here.  Can you include a [mcve] with the actual image and command names, the Dockerfile if it's a custom image, and the complete `docker run` command with all of its options (especially `-v`)?

Comment: Maybe the `docker` command at your shell prompt is a function or alias?  When make runs a command it doesn't know anything about shell functions or aliases.  Try running `type -a docker` at your shell prompt to see.  Also make sure that your makefile is not changing directories, or changing the PATH, or some similar thing.